# ¿Cómo se puede guardar de forma eficiente un excel grande en apache poi?

Tags: excel, apache-poi, out-of-memory-error

Tengo un fichero CSV con 150000 filas de datos. Al tratar de escribirlo en el excel, he encontrado un problema al tratar de escribirlo, pues recibo un OutOfMemoryError. He tratado de usar varios métodos, pero no consigo que funcionen:

- Usar SXSSF en lugar de XSSF y escribir cada cierto numero de filas.
- Usar XSSF y escribir en el libro cada cierto numero de filas.

*Nota: He usado tanto CellReference como Cell para ver que funcionaba mejor, pero en ambos me surge un problema adicional: hay algunas filas que me devuelven `null`, pero si trato de hacer un `createRow` no funciona pues dice que ya he creado dicha fila. Solo usando Row y Cell soy capaz de hacer que funcione, pero no con CellReference.*

### Usar SXSSF en lugar de XSSF y escribir cada cierto numero de filas

El método que uso es el siguiente:

```
for(int i = 0; i < datosAux.size(); i++) {
    Row row = hojaRellenar.getRow(i + 10);
        for (int j = 0; j < datosAux.get(i).length; j++) {
            Cell cell;
            if (row == null) {
                hojaRellenar.createRow(i + 10);
                row = hojaRellenar.getRow(i + 10);
            }
            cell = row.getCell(j, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
            if(cell != null)
                cell.setCellValue(datosAux.get(i)[j]);
            else {
                cell = row.createCell(j);
                cell.setCellValue(datosAux.get(i)[j]);
            }
        }
        if(i % 100 == 0) {
            libroAct.write(fout);
            ((SXSSFSheet) libroAct.getSheet(DetailsSH)).flushRows(100);
        }
    }
```

La variable `datosAux` es de tipo `List<String[]>`, el cual ha sido rellenado previamente con los datos del CSV. Dado que mis datos deben ser impresos a partir de la celda A11 (Fila 10, Columna 0), uso la linea `Row row = hojaRellenar.getRow(i + 10);` para que empiece desde aquí.

Este código, sin embargo, produce un error con `row` que produce un error al tratar de crearla. Sin embargo, si es nula, no debería dar problemas para crear la fila.

### Escribir en el libro cada cierto numero de filas

El método se parece mucho al anterior, salvo por el flush.

```
for(int i = 0; i < datosAux.size(); i++) {
    Row row = hojaRellenar.getRow(i + 10);
        for (int j = 0; j < datosAux.get(i).length; j++) {
            Cell cell;
            if (row == null) {
                hojaRellenar.createRow(i + 10);
                row = hojaRellenar.getRow(i + 10);
            }
            cell = row.getCell(j, Row.MissingCellPolicy.CREATE_NULL_AS_BLANK);
            if(cell != null)
                cell.setCellValue(datosAux.get(i)[j]);
            else {
                cell = row.createCell(j);
                cell.setCellValue(datosAux.get(i)[j]);
            }
        }
        if(i % 100 == 0) {
            libroAct.write(fout);
        }
    }
```

Sin embargo, este método parece no funcionar, pues parece agregar datos al excel eternamente y tarda muchísimo en ejecutar (suficiente como para no tener paciencia para que termine).

Por otro lado, este código produce un archivo mucho mayor de lo que debería, pues he comprobado que, pasando los ficheros del CSV a través de una macro, el tamaño de este fichero y el que está generando mi programa es demasiado diferente (del órden de 7mb en el original y +200mb en el que se está creando).

**Nota:** Si uso menos datos, el excel se corrompe.

¿Qué puede estar sucediendo?

Comment: La maquina virtual (JVM) se quedó sin memoria. Cuando corres el programa tenés que pasarle argumentos a la jvm para que tenga más memoria disponible (Para java 8 el parámetro -Xmx debería ser suficiente) La cantidad máxima de memeria que podes asignar depende tanto de la version de java como de la capacidad física instalada, como de si estás usando un SO de 32 o de 64 bits. Con la clase Runtime podes checkear la memoria total y disponible que tiene la jvm.

Comment: He conseguido mejorar destinando más memoria, pero aún y así, no puedo escribir más de 140100 filas...

Comment: Por un lado fijate si estás usando esta forma de generar el excel que mantiene en memoria solo algunas de las filas del archivo (especificado cuantas a la hora de crear el workbook (o la planilla): http://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf.

Comment: Si eso no funciona, tal vez podés liberar un poco de memoria usando un archivo (o secuencial ordenado, o de acceso aleatorio) como almacenamiento temporario en lugar de mantener la lista de datos en memoria (ArrayList). En otra época donde había que hacer todo en 640K esta era la forma de procesar grandes cantidades de datos :)